# On a Mac, within the shell, how can I tell that I have a GUI?

Tags: macos, unix, shell, environment-variables

Because you (lovely) people are always so curious about posters' original intents, here's mine:

> If I'm on a Mac and have a GUI (as opposed to, say, being on an ssh session), I want to set my `$EDITOR` to `mate_wait`. (And go with `vim` otherwise.)

And, you have an answer for that. I do too. It even works. Here. Sometimes.

So I want you to fiercely scrutinize it:

#### Skip intro

I can tell that I'm on a Mac by checking:

```
[ `uname` = 'Darwin' ]
```

And I think I can sort of tell that I have a GUI by checking:

```
[ "$TERM_PROGRAM" = 'Apple_Terminal' ]
  # or
[ "$DISPLAY" ]
```

Now, it's theoretically possible that I have an Aqua-less OpenDarwin setup running X11. It's also possible that I'm running fully lickable Mac GUI, yet using another terminal application.

And then there's the mind-bending possibility that I'm running xterm within Apple's X11 running on top of the OS X GUI. In which case I'd still want `mate_wait` as `$EDITOR`.

For OCD's sake, I'd like my checks to be as precise as possible.

So, please, un-reckless-fy my code.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a stab at this, mind you it's probably incomplete.
Condition 1: Am I local

```
[ -z "$SSH_CLIENT" ]
```

Condition 2: Am I remote

```
[ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]
```

Condition 3: Do I have the lickable mac GUI

```
[ -n "`ps -fe | grep '[W]indowServer'`" ]
```

So putting these together:

```
if [ -z "$SSH_CLIENT" -a -n "`ps -fe | grep '[W]indowServer'`" ]; then
     EDITOR="matew"
else
     EDITOR=vim
fi
```

You will need a script called 'matew' that simply does:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec mate -w "$*"
```

as EDITOR is only expected to be a direct command, and won't work if it's 'mate -w' (at least on snow leopard).

Comment: mate -w actually works (or so I remember), but you can symlink mate as mate_wait and when called as such it'll assume -w

Comment: can you assume that you're local just because you're not SSH-ed? (I guess telnet and all that)

Comment: as for grepping for the WindowServer, well, I'm trying to find a problem with it, but I guess if you know you're local, then you're good.

Comment: Unfortunately, WindowServer's there whether or not you're in its session, so I don't think this is a useful test.

Comment: That's true, but what are the odds that you're local, and running WindowServer and you're not logged on? Unless you're on a serial connection, I can't see how this would affect interactive logons

Comment: How about `if [ -z "$SSH_CLIENT" ] && ps -axc -ouid,command | grep -sq "$UID loginwindow\$"; then` ... That tests whether there's an instance of loginwindow with the same effective UID as you, which should only be the case if there's a GUI login session for your user, which excludes cases like where you've su'd to another user.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask `launchctl` what is managing the current session.

```
if [ "$(launchctl managername)" == Aqua ]; then
    EDITOR="matew";
else
    EDITOR="vim";
fi;
```

Comment: This seems to work for me; over SSH connections `launchctl managername` prints `Background` instead.

Comment: This prints `Background` when I run this command inside tmux in the GUI even when I'm not using an SSH connection.

Comment: Interesting. This behavior seems specific to `tmux`, perhaps after they integrated `reattach-to-user-namespace`, which implies it's intentional. If I use Apple's built in `/usr/bin/screen` instead, I see `Aqua`. I wonder if it's a bug?

Comment: This seems potentially related, but I still don't know the fine-grained mechanics of what's happening here: https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard/issues/78